# local atlassian stash server error debugging plugin

Tags: githooks, bitbucket-server

Im trying to setup a dev environment to create a git hook plugin for Atlassian stash server. When I run atlas-debug to start the web server then browse to localhost:port The Stash home page doesn't display and I get this error in the console...

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2015-03-10 21:09:51,279 WARN  [threadpool:thread-15]  c.a.s.i.s.g.t.DefaultTranscodeServer GET /stash HTTP/1.1
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Host: localhost:52883
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Connection: keep-alive
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Pragma: no-cache
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Cache-Control: no-cache
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  could not be transcoded; ignoring request
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified path, GET /stash HTTP/1.1
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Host: localhost:52883
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Connection: keep-alive
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Pragma: no-cache
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Cache-Control: no-cache
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] , does not belong to Stash and cannot be transcoded.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.transcode.DefaultTranscoder.transcode(DefaultTranscoder.java:52) ~[stash-scm-git-3.7.1.jar:na]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.transcode.DefaultTranscodeServer$TranscodeChannelHandler.transcode(DefaultTranscodeServer.java:162) [stash-scm-git-3.7.1.jar:na]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.transcode.DefaultTranscodeServer$TranscodeChannelHandler.run(DefaultTranscodeServer.java:138) [stash-scm-git-3.7.1.jar:na]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.stash.internal.concurrent.StateTransferringExecutor$StateTransferringRunnable.run(StateTransferringExecutor.java:71) [stash-platform-3.7.1.jar:na]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_75]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_75]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_75]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_75]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 1 frame trimmed
```

I'm running on Mac OSX 10.9.5 with javac 1.7.0_75

I installed the Atlassian plugin SDK with brew

```
brew install atlassian/tap/atlassian-plugin-sdk
```

created an empty plugin with

```
atlas-create-stash-plugin
```

created a default post repository hook with

```
atlas-create-stash-plugin-module
```

then started the server with

```
atlas-debug
```

and when I browse to localhost I get the error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems i had a mis match in java versions. setting JAVA_HOME to the right version helped